# Is there no Development Mode for Sandboxes?

Tags: sandbox, development-mode

I enabled the **Development Mode** in my Settings but it does not show up.
Neither in Firefox nore in Chrome or Edge.

The [Documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=pages_dev_mode.htm) says:

> Available in: Contact Manager, Group, Professional, Enterprise,
>   Performance, Unlimited, and Developer Editions

Does that mean there is no Development Mode for **Sandboxes**?

Comment: Try to refresh the page displayed in the dev mode. For me it was only shown for the second time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was trying to see the Dev Mode for a page that was part of a Managed Package.

Of cause, you can not see development details for a packaged component.
So there is no way to get access to the view state in customer orgs :(

Answer (score 1):

Developement mode exist in sandbox.Just check the current user development mode 
checkbox in user section and refresh the page.

Comment: I did.. I logged out and in, changes the browser, logged in, changed to another one, logged in, nothing :( But thanks for your answer, I will open a case.

Comment: yeah..bcz in my sandbox its working fine..Hope so sales force helps you.